# Assume $f(x)$ is a 1D map exhibiting a period-3 orbit P. Then is P a period 3 orbit of $f(f(x))$?

Tags: periodic-functions, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Assume $f(x)$ is a 1D map exhibiting a period-3 orbit P. Then P is a period 3 orbit of $f(f(x))$?

I know this is a somewhat elementary question but I'm only asking it to confirm if my thought process is correct and applicable for more complex problems.

A period 3 orbit would mean $f(x) = (a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c........ etc)$

so would I be correct in saying $f(f(x)) = (b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow a........ etc)$

and therefore P is the same period 3 orbit and the statement in my question is true. Would appreciate if anybody could verify that I am thinking about this in the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like it would be  b -> a -> c -> b .> .... for the map $f^2$  (same points on the orbit but in reverse order).

Comment: So would it be true to say that P is the same orbit in both cases (albeit in a different order)?

Comment: Depends on whether you define "orbit" as a set of points or a sequence of points  -- as a set of points, they are the same.